# Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus, pymodbus3

I' trying to connect from my Mac laptop to a Modbus device ([MR-SI4](http://www.metz-connect.com/us/system/files/productfiles/Modbus_software_manual.pdf)) using a serial connection using a USB RS485 converter that gets "mounted" to `/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART`.

This is my code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.constants import Defaults
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

# settings for USB-RS485 adapter
SERIAL = '/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART'
BAUD = 19200

# set Modbus defaults

Defaults.UnitId = 1
Defaults.Retries = 5

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=SERIAL, stopbits=1, bytesize=8, timeout=3, baudrate=BAUD, parity='E')

connection = client.connect()
print "Readout started"

#result = client.read_discrete_inputs(0)
#result = client.read_holding_registers(12,19)
result = client.read_input_registers(0,1)
print(result)
```

The output in the console is:

```
$ sudo python test.py 
Readout started
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:send: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x31 0xca
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:will sleep to wait for 3.5 char
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:recv: 
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:getting transaction 1
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit
```

I would love to have a little help understanding the error I'm getting. I tried with the configuration of `pymodbus` and also with different functions like `read_discrete_inputs` or `read_holding_registers`. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: The logs says, The remote unit did not return any response for your request, If you see the line with `DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:recv:` , you got nothing back with in the read time out of 3 seconds. I would say to check your connections (grounding) and double check the parity and baudrates.

Answer (score 6):

When working with modbus, even if you're using an high-level library, it's always useful to have close at hand the offical [modbus documentation](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf).
With the documentation, you can check what each byte of your frame means:

```
0x01 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x31 0xCA
```

The first byte is the device address `(0x01)`

The second byte is the function code `(0x04, Read Input Registers)`

Third and fourth bytes are the starting position `(0x00, 0x00)`

Fifth and sixth bytes are the quantity of outputs `(0x00, 0x01)`

The last 2 bytes are the CRC control `(0x31, 0xCA)`

This means that you are asking for one `(0x00, 0x01)` registers from the input registers `(0x04)` from the first position in memory `(0x00, 0x00)` from device with address 1 `(0x01)`.

The frame by itself is correct, and if the device software/firmware follows the modbus standard, you should have an answer: the register that you asked for OR an error frame `(0x01, 0x80, crc, crc)`.

This said, we can check why you do not receive an answer from your device. For doing this, if you're not sure about your code/on what you're asking/how your device behave, you can use an external tool to compare the results. I'd suggest you somethink like [docklight](https://docklight.de/), that helps you to set up your connection and send/receive modbus frame.

First thing I'd check are the connection parameters:

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=SERIAL, stopbits=1, bytesize=8, timeout=3, baudrate=BAUD, parity='E')
```

> Method is correct, since is the protocol you're asking for.
>
> The port is correct, otherwise it gives back a system error.
>
> Timeout is what raise the error: in a given time, no response was received. Anyway the problem is probably not here, since you set a high value for timeout.
>
> Stopbits should not interfere with the frame reception.
>
> The problem could be in baudrate and parity: an error here can cause the error raised by your code.

If you do not know the correct value for baudrate and/or parity, you can try with the [most commons baudrates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/what-standard-uart-rates-are-there) and the parity values: `'N', 'E', 'O', 'M', 'S'` (stands for: None, Even, Odd, Mark, Space. Default is None).

If i've to bet, i'd start by replacing Even parity with None (`parity = 'N'`).

If you still have the problem, the device address (`0x01`) may be wrong. The address can be represented a value from 0 (`0x00`) to 255 (`0xFF`).

By protocol standard, even if the starting address (`0x00, 0x00`), the quantity of outputs (`0x00, 0x01)` or the crc (`0x31, 0xCA`) are wrong, the device should respond something, but it's no always like that: if you think you're in this situation, research for device's specific documentation.

The last possibility is to use a low level library, such as [PySerial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/), and you define your own protocol.

Comment: This helped me debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue by setting the constant `RetryOnEmpty` to `True`.

```
from pymodbus.constants import Defaults
Defaults.RetryOnEmpty = True
```

It also may be useful to configure a timeout and some retries.

```
Defaults.Timeout = 5
Defaults.Retries = 5
```

https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/library/constants.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Stack_post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045057/3702377).

You can handle the error:

```
if not result.isError():
    '''isError() method implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above'''

    print(result.registers)  # Note.

else:
    # Handle Error.
    print('Unable to read or there is the connection problem.')
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- In many cases, RTU parity is None: `parity='N'`
- Make sure from root permission on your serial port (`/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART`).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had similar error where there was no response. My device address was wrong. It was 1 i.e unit = 1. It was supposed to be zero.
i.e `client.read_holding_registers(500,1,unit=0)`

```
import pymodbus
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
client = ModbusSerialClient( method = 'rtu', port = "COM4", stopbits = 1, 
bytesize = 8, baudrate=9600 , parity= 'N')
client.connect()
result = client.read_holding_registers(500,1,unit=0)
print(result)
```

> 0x0 0x3 0x1 0xf4 0x0 0x1 0xc5 0xd5

Otherwise error output was

> 0x1 0x3 0x1 0xf4 0x0 0x1 0xc5 0xd5