# How do I fix a PyModbus Unable to decode Response-Error with IF96015 Interface by IME

Tags: python, tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I have a PyModbus running on a *Raspberry PI 3b*. I have the *IF96015* Ethernet Interface for the *Nemo 96HD* Digital Multimeter. When I try to connect to it over ModbusTCP with the PyModbus console I can ask if it is connected and it says "true" but I cannot read any data from it.

According to the manuals the first used address is `301` and when I try to read the `.Coil()` I get:

```
"original_function_code": "1 (0x1)", 
"error": "[Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response"
```

Open the Console:

```
pymodbus.console tcp --host 192.168.178.200 --port 502
```

Check for connection:

```
client.connect
```

Try to read a Coil:

```
client.read_coils address 301 count 1
```

Output:

```
"original_function_code": "1 (0x1)", 
"error": "[Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)"
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Manuals of the *IF96015*:

[Manual_1](http://www.ime-messgeraete.de/ime-d-manuel-pdf/10782310.pdf)

[Manual_2](http://www.imeitaly.com/protocolli/PR106.pdf)

Comment: Can you put on your code?

Comment: Which code do you mean? Because it is running in the pymodbus Console.

Comment: I have a Example Code 

rom pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.178.200')
result = client.read_coils(0x301)
print(result)
client.close()


This will give me an Output of:
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)

Comment: Please put your full code in your question for better express shown. I think you need to `unit` argument and using `result.registers` instead of result, So I suggest to you put on your code for better interaction

Comment: What do you mean of by PyModbus console?

Comment: When you install pyModBus you can type pymodbus.console to get A Console prompt

Comment: I dont have much more code than that because I use the console to try everything out

Comment: So can you put on your commands that you have on pymodbus.console on your question (On your question, not in this place (comment section))?!

Comment: Did you try `unit` argument in `read_coil()` method? check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52791339/3702377) for more information.

Comment: How can I determine the Unit Id in this Case?

Comment: I added all the commands i have used

Comment: I didn't know about this tool, thanks +1, I will post an answer for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. The problem is in the default value for the unit ID. The manual which can be found at the [vendor's website](http://www.imeitaly.com/docs/10782690W.pdf) shows an example Modbus TCP packet format with unit ID value set to "1".

But the factory setting for unit ID is "255". You can change the default address in a menu, password 3002. Now, I can read values with the following Python code:

```
message = tcp.read_holding_registers(slave_id=255, starting_address=0x1000, quantity=6)
response = tcp.send_message(message, sock)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each Modbus slave/server has a *unit_ID*, so you need to add this on `.read_coil()` method.

In many cases `unit` argument is equal to `1` as default in Modbus slave side.

---

Here is an example (Modbus client):

```
pymodbus.console tcp --host 192.168.178.200 --port 502
client.connect
client.read_coils address=301 count=1 unit=1
```

---

Here is another example with multiple reading with `.read_holding_registers()` and its decoder:

```
client.read_holding_registers count=4 address=9 unit=1
{
    "registers": [
        60497,
        47134,
        34091,
        15424
    ]
}


result.raw
{
    "registers": [
        15626,
        55203,
        28733,
        18368
    ]
}

result.decode word_order=little byte_order=little formatters=float64
28.17
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `read_coil()` read/write digital values (1 bit)
- `read_holding_registers()` read/write analog values (16 bits)
- Some address are hexadecimal (maybe `0x301` instead `301`)
- Don't forget `=` after each argument like this (`count=1` instead of `count 1`)

Comment: Could you determiniert in the Manual 2 wheiter 301 is a Register or a coil?

Comment: When I try client.read_holding_registers I get this 

> client.read_holding_registers address=301 count=1 unit=1                                                                                                                                                  
{
    "original_function_code": "3 (0x3)", 
    "error": "[Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)"
}

>

Comment: And with 0x301 I get:   

> client.read_holding_registers address=0x301 count=1 unit=1                                                                                                                                                
ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x301'",)

Comment: It is the same as with the registers

Comment: Is your example with the Multiple Registers for this Device?

Comment: So your problem may be in the address, I'll read the manual_2

Comment: No, I tested it with a Delta_PLC and Delta_gateway, that these are Modbus TCP, but I know about that registers address and read count and unit_ID

Comment: Ah ok so I should be a Address mistake?

Comment: I think it maybe yes.

Comment: I have tried

> client.read_device_information                                                                                                                                                                            
{
    "original_function_code": "43 (0x2b)", 
    "error": "[Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response"
}

>  

so there is no address wich could be wrong but I get the error to

Comment: try with the `--verbose` option and share the logs.

Comment: It could be that you are using the wrong address, the offset is in hex and the console takes the values as plain int , so you will have to explicitly convert the hex to int and use the offset (`0x301 == 769`)

Comment: @DJCheeky check the "Sanju" comments.

Answer (score 1):

In Manual 2, the address is `0x301` hex.
Try `client.read_coils address = 769 count = 1`.
Addresses should be given in decimal format (hex `0x301` = dec `769`).