# Modbus RTU using pymodbus - unable to read holding register from modbus data

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbus

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
import logging

def readModbusData():
    logging.basicConfig()
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    client=ModbusClient(method='rtu',port='COM3',
    baudrate=9600,timeout=1,parity='N',stopbits=2)
    print(client.connect())
    client.debug_enabled()

    log.debug("Read holding registers")
    response=client.read_holding_registers(0,1)

    print(response) #This returns the response for whole length of registers

    # print(response.getRegister(0));  #This returns value of only one 
    
    client.close()
readModbusData()
```

#### Console logs:

> DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x0 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x85 0xdb
> DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
> DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
> Modbus Error: [Input/Output]
> Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)

Comment: I suggest that you test the Modbus device with (instead of your python code) CAS Modbus Scanner (free) or Modbus Poll (free trial). Both are Modbus master/client tools that I know work. If your it works with those tools, then your problem is in your code code; if it does not work with them, the problem is in the Modbus slave device.

Comment: You need to pass the device address `response=client.read_holding_registers(0,1, unit=<your slave address here>)`

Comment: it worked with minimalmodbus.Thanks everyone for their response.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [stack_post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045057/3702377),

You forgot the `unit` argument and using `print(response.registers)` instead of  `print(response)`.

You should having like the following snippet code:

```
response = client.read_holding_registers(0, 1, unit=<set-the-unit-ID>)  # Note.

if not response.isError():
    '''isError() method implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above'''

    print(response.registers)  # Note.

else:
    # Handle Error.
    print('Unable to read or there is the connection problem.')
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- In many cases `unit` is `1` in slave side as default.